# 404 issue when image src is null

Tags: html, angular

I have a code that use img tag to show an image. The issue is that when the image src is null i get an error that says 404 error.How can i solve this issue. I'll share my code below.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.itemTitle" id="container">
                          
                          <img class="img thumbnail" (click)="openDialogImg(myTemplate)"
                            *ngSwitchCase="
                              ['Graph1', 'Graph2'].includes(item.itemTitle)
                                ? item.itemTitle
                                : !item.itemTitle
                            "
                            [src]="_sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item.itemValue)"
                            alt="Graph"
                          /> 
                          <!-- this template is invisible. It will be shown in the popup -->
                         <ng-template #myTemplate>                          
                           <!-- this is a big popup image.  -->
                           <img [src]="_sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item.itemValue)" style="height:100%; width:100%">
                           <button id = "x" mat-button (click)="myDialogRef?.close()">X</button>
                         </ng-template>                        
                          <span *ngSwitchDefault>{{ item.itemValue }}</span>
                        </ng-container>
```

when graph1 and graph2 image data is null i get the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

When the image source gives you `null` the browser is searching for an image named `null`. Since you don't have an image with that name, the 404 (not found) error is actually correct.

Try to have a if statement around your `<img>` checking for the source first. If there is no source (`null`), don't print the `<img>` tag into the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a clause to check if the image src == null. If it is, you can put a replacer image or don't execute the  tag at all.